# Quicksort on an set of length 2

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

When quicksorting a dataset the list gets split down and is recursive, in that the solution calls itself on the smaller lists.
I was practising quicksort on an algorithm but a sublist of length 2 is a stone in my shoe, I can't solve it. The original list was:

```
2  0  1  7  4  3  5  6
```

Pivot being at 2, left at 0, right at 6, I start. Left moves along to 7, 7>=2. Right moves down to 1, 1<=2. Left and right have crossed. As I understand, now right becomes the split point and two new lists are formed.

```
2  0      1      7  4  3  5  6
```

As you can see, the first list, 2 and 0, is 2 items long. So 2 is the pivot, and 0 is both left and right. Left doesn't move along, right moves along to 2, 2<=2. Left and right have crossed so p replaces R and L onwards is a new list. But this leaves 2 and 0 unsorted.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: for small arrays use bubble or insertion sort

Comment: As mentioned quicksorting creates smaller lists

Comment: Yes, and when array's become small enough you call `insertionSort` on it.

Comment: On a list of length 2 the partition portion of the quicksort will sort the list. A list of length 1 or less is your base case

Comment: @Yola It's worth pointing out using bubble or insertion sort for small arrays is an *optimization* - a working quicksort implementation should work fine all the way down to 1 or 0 elements, even if that might be a bit slower than the hybrid approach.

Comment: This is a problem with lists of any length. 2 0 | 1 | ... is already wrong. Everything on the left must be smaller than (or possibly equal to) the pivot, because the pivot won't move again. You can fix this by either swapping the pivot with the last smaller element (1 with 2 and 2/1 with 0), or not treating the pivot separately, which will in this case lead to the swaps as above. See the code on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) (or you might want to check your textbook instead, if applicable).

Comment: @Dukeling you are right, so I provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case came from the fact that i don't move pivot in its sorted place. After the partitioning with pivot `2` your array should look like this:

```
0  1  2  7  4  3  5  6
      ^
```

Let's go through `partition` procedure with the input array `13 19 9 5 12 8 7 4 21 2 6 11`. And let's choose `11` as a pivot.

During the procedure, you need to maintain two pointers, one for the element just before the first element bigger than the pivot `^^`, and another one for the current you are looking at `||`.

The code looks like this:

```
A is array left..right
pivot = A[right]
i = left - 1                 // the one before the first bigger than the pivot
for j = left to right - 1
    if A[j] <= pivot
        i = i + 1
        swap A[i] with A[j]
swap A[i+1] with A[right]    // put pivot at its place, i + 1 - is the index to split on
```

And the example:

```
    13  19   9   5  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11 

    13  19   9   5  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11   13 > 11, skip
^^  ||

    13  19   9   5  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11   19 > 11, skip
^^      ||

     9  19  13   5  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11    9 < 11, swap
    ^^      ||

     9   5  13  19  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11    5 < 11, swap
        ^^      ||

     9   5  13  19  12   8   7   4  21   2   6  11   12 > 11, skip
        ^^          ||

     9   5   8  19  12  13   7   4  21   2   6  11    8 < 11, swap
            ^^          ||

     9   5   8   7  12  13  19   4  21   2   6  11    7 < 11, swap
                ^^          ||

     9   5   8   7   4  13  19  12  21   2   6  11    4 < 11, swap
                    ^^          ||

     9   5   8   7   4  13  19  12  21   2   6  11   21 > 11, skip
                    ^^              ||
```

can you continue yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The quicksort algorithm only has base case of empty array or array of size 1. In your case of [2  0] , the algorithm chooses 2 as a pivot, partitions [2  0] into empty array and array [0] and merges it with pivot [2], giving sorted array [0  2].